# How to fully use the CPU in Matlab [Improving performance of a repetitive, time-consuming program]

Tags: matlab, time, consuming, particle-swarm

I'm working on an adaptive and Fully automatic segmentation algorithm under varying light condition  , the core of this algorithm uses Particle swarm Optimization(PSO)  to tune the fuzzy system  and believe me it's very time consuming :| for only 5 particles and 100 iterations I have to wait 2 to 3 hours ! and it's just processing  one image from my data set containing over 100 photos !

I'm using matlab R2013 ,with a intel coer i7-2670Qm @ 2.2GHz //8.00GB RAM//64-bit operating system

**the problem is : when starting the program it uses only 12%-16% of my CPU and only one core is working !!**

I've searched a lot and came into matlabpool so I added this line to my code :

```
matlabpool open 8
```

now when I start the program the task manger shows 98% CPU usage, but it's just for  a few seconds ! after that it came back to 12-13% CPU usage :|

Do you have any idea how can I get this code run faster ?!

Comment: I dont know enough to comment on speeding up this code, however your description indicates that the above code might only use one thread. Since you indicated you have 100's of files, you could explore the idea of processing 4+ files at a time (tweak the number to get most CPU utilization). i.e put a parfor (1:numfiles) around this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

12 Percent sounds like Matlab is using only one Thread/Core and this one with with full load, which is normal.

`matlabpool open 8` is not enough, this simply opens workers. You have to use commands like parfor, to assign work to them.

Comment: thanks Daniel for your reply ,
Due to the competitive  nature of PSO algorithm ,do you think it's possible to use parfor in PSO loop ? in each iteration we need to compare particle best_fit with each other and also with Global_best!

Answer (score 1):

Further to Daniel's suggestion, ideally to apply PARFOR you'd find a time-consuming FOR loop in you algorithm where the iterations are independent and convert that to PARFOR. Generally, PARFOR works best when applied at the outermost level possible. It's also definitely worth using the MATLAB profiler to help you optimise your serial code before you start adding parallelism.

Comment: Using  MATLAB profiler I found out the Fit function is the most time-consuming loop in my program ,which is inside the PSO main loop , I cant use parfor with PSO loop as I explained to Daniel  , but do you have any suggestion for this loop ? 
`for i=1:SzTrain
[output, IRR, ORR, ARR] =evalfis([train(i,1);train(i,2);train(i,3)],fis);
           ...
        end`

Comment: @Amir: This single line of code is useless, the key point are dependencies between one iteration and the next.

Comment: @Daniel R:
could explain a bit more ?
PSO iterations depends on each other , It(n+1) depends on it(n).
you suggest parfor? because iterations depends on each other ?

Comment: @Amir: Yep, it's not straight forward. A basic idea for many optimization problems is to let each worker try one step and take the best. Include your code if you need detailed help.

Comment: @ Daniel R I've added the main PSO loop ,is that enough ?

Comment: @DanielR  would you pls give me your email adress ?

Comment: @Amir: I did not answer, because I can't give any detailed help without seeing your code. I don't see any reason to discuss this on private channels, create a question including your code and we will see who can help.

Comment: @DanielR ,Dear Daniel I've had actually include my code and tagged your name but you didn't answer(about a month ago)...anyway I changed my code, the main iteration loop stays the same but I've used "Parfor" in the inner loop where particles are updated ,now it's using all my 8 CPUs :) I have another question about the fit function and if there is anyway to speed that one up too ,i thought maybe it's better to ask you in private than open another thread , but if you suggest to  open another thread i'll do that ,thanks again for your cmnt .

Answer (score 0):

With my own simulations I find that I cannot recode them using Parfor, the for loops I have are too intertwined to take advantage of multiple cores.

HOWEVER:

You can open a second (and third, and fourth etc) instance of Matlab and tell this additional instance to run another job. Each instance of matlab open will use a different core. So if you have a quadcore, you can have 4 instances open and get 100% efficiency by running code in all 4.

So, I gained efficiency by having multiple instances of matlab open at the same time and running a job. My jobs took 8 to 27 hours at a time, and as one might imagine without liquid cooling I burnt out my cpu fan and had to replace it.

Also do look into optimizing your matlab code, I recently optimized my code and now it runs 40% faster.